# Installing Superset from Scratch

Tags: apache-superset

There was a problem during installation superset from Scratch:

command: `sudo superset fab create-admin`

Error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py)

Answer (score 0):

From the path in the error message (`/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py`), it appears you are using Python 3.7. At the time of writing, Apache Superset requires Python 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10.

Sources: [1](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docs/docs/contributing/local-backend.mdx#os-dependencies) [2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/v8490vf1horzcy7h5f8oh6xdxh0z2rb2) [3](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch/#:%7E:text=You%20should%20install%20a%20recent%20version%20of%20Python%20(the%20official%20docker%20image%20uses%203.8.12))

Comment: apache-superset==1.5.1
Classifiers
Programming Language
Python :: 3.7
Python :: 3.8
Python :: 3.9
https://pypi.org/project/apache-superset/1.5.1/

Comment: It seems the PyPI listing is not up to date as `TypedDict` was added to the `typing` module in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#typing)